# Transform struct A to B

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, type-conversion, c++17

I have two structures with same internal structure.

```
struct From {
  struct X {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> ids;
  };

  struct Y {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<X> x_vec;
  }; 
  std::vector<Y> y_vec;
};

struct To {
  struct X {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> ids;
  };

  struct Y {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<X> x_vec;
  }; 
  std::vector<Y> y_vec;
};
```

I would like to convert / transform from one type to another, in this case (From -> To).
Is there a efficient way to accomplish this?

```
To convertFrom(From obj);
```

Comment: Why do you need two different types if they're identical inside anyway?

Comment: You can write constructors and assignment operators that take references to the other struct type.

Comment: "Is there a efficient way to accomplish this?" The compiler will take care of making this efficient, pretty much regardless of how you approach this. (unless you intentionally do it in as bone-headed of a way as possible, obviously)

Comment: That being said, if you want to learn more about this general subject, you should lookup the notion of [layout compatibility](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout)

Comment: @Dmitri One datatype is coming from a header file in a library and we don't want to expose the datatypes from that library in the whole code. So want to convert it before using it

Comment: @Daemon You could also put the library struct as a private member of a custom wrapper class

Comment: *"we don't want to expose the datatypes from that library in the whole code"* -- yet you are willing to expose an equivalent data type in the whole code simply because it is under your control? Hmm... That does make sense if you intend to keep your data type even if the library changes its type. Of course, you lose your efficient transform in that situation. If the design decision has been thought through this much, I might find it reasonable.

Comment: @MatG But if I wrap it a different wrapper class, I will need to expose multiple methods to access the data, which more or less will be like converting from library struct to local struct.

Comment: @Daemon Probably involves more work, but could avoid data duplication and define an interface that you control. Only you can know if it's worth it or not

Comment: Hmm... is the problem that `From` is defined in a header with a bunch of *other* types, and you don't want those other types exposed to your code? Also, given the aversion to a wrapper class, is the efficiency concern about runtime efficiency or is it about code efficiency? The more I think about this, the more details (restrictions) I find missing from the (end of the) question. As the question stands, a valid answer would be `using To = From;` yet the comments suggest that this might be unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct From {
  struct X {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> ids;
  };

  struct Y {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<X> x_vec;
  }; 
  std::vector<Y> y_vec;
};

struct To {
  struct X {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<int> ids;

    explicit X(From::X&& x) 
        :name(std::move(x.name)), ids(std::move(x.ids)) {}
  };

  struct Y {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<X> x_vec;

    explicit Y(From::Y&& y) 
        :name(std::move(y.name)), 
        x_vec(std::make_move_iterator(y.x_vec.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(y.x_vec.end())) 
     {}
  }; 
  std::vector<Y> y_vec;

  explicit To(From&& f)  
    :x_vec(std::make_move_iterator(f.y_vec.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(f.y_vec.end()))
  {}
};
```

Move constructors are as efficient as you can be, and making them `explicit` prevents accidental mistakes.  Since you're doing type conversions at almost every step, the move isn't as efficient as it first appears, but it *is* as efficient as is possible. Since they're just constructors, usage is trivial:

```
int main() {
   From from = ...;
   To to = std::move(from);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform` is pretty useful for transformations:

```
To convertFrom(From obj) {
    auto toX = [](auto&& fromX) -> To::X {
        return {
            std::move(fromX.name),
            std::move(fromX.ids),
        };
    };
    auto toY = [=](auto&& fromY) -> To::Y {
        std::vector<To::X> x_vec;
        std::transform(
            std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(fromY.x_vec)),
            std::make_move_iterator(std::end(fromY.x_vec)),
            std::back_inserter(x_vec),
            toX
        );
        return {
            std::move(fromY.name),
            std::move(x_vec),
        };
    };
    std::vector<To::Y> y_vec;
    std::transform(
        std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(obj.y_vec)),
        std::make_move_iterator(std::end(obj.y_vec)),
        std::back_inserter(y_vec),
        toY
    );
    return {std::move(y_vec)};
}
```

---

A more efficient solution is to avoid the conversion.

> One datatype is coming from a header file in a library and we don't want to expose the datatypes from that library in the whole code. So want to convert it before using it

You could instead define a wrapper class that uses the PIMPL pattern to hide the library class inside. This introduces some indirection, but has requires no conversion. This could potentially be more efficient depending on how the class is used. Tthis would actually de-couple the interface from the library because you wouldn't need to be maintaining a duplicate type in parallel.